# How to check if date is 3 days before current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this Javascript code, where I have a condition for 3 days after the current date and one for the current day. I would need to add a condition for 3 days previous to the current date. How can I do that?

```
$('.entry-date').each(function() {
    var dateString = $(this).text();
    var parts = dateString.split("-");
    var date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2]), parseInt(parts[1])-1, parts[0]);
    var now = new Date();
    var diff = dateDiffInDays(now, date);

    if ((diff < 3) && (diff > 0)) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("new-entry"); 
    }

    if (diff == 0) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("today");  
    }
});
```

Comment: How about `if (diff < -3){   }`

Comment: check if you parse the dates correctly, and checkout this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: are you asking for an implementation to the dateDiffInDays function?

Comment: if (diff < -3)
This is what I was looking! Thanks